# Multiple JQuery gallery in one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I am using "Responsive Image Gallery" based on JQuery.

Links to the actual Gallery Code:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/

I am trying to have **two gallery in single page** and **toggle** these two galleries using a button.
Lets say gallery1 and gallery2 where gallery1 has active class and thus gallery2 is with display:none; property.

How do I accomplish that with this particular plugin?

The gallery.js file has this code:

```
// gallery container
    var $rgGallery = $('#rg-gallery')
```

Where its addressing an ID block of gallery. Thus if I use:

```
<div id="rg-gallery">
//gallery code here
</div>

<div id="rg-gallery">
// gallery code here
<div>
```

then it won't work.

So I tried with classes. But with this:

```
<div class="rg-gallery">
//gallery code here
</div>

<div class="rg-gallery">
// gallery code here
<div>
```

only the second gallery works and the first one doesn't.

Therefore I think that I need to give different ID to different gallery blocks as follows:

```
<div id="rg-gallery1">
//gallery code here
</div>

<div id="rg-gallery2">
// gallery code here
<div>
```

But then how do I adjust the gallery.js code to address multiple gallery blocks.
It's just addressing a single gallery at the moment with this code:

```
var $rgGallery = $('#rg-gallery')
```

I am a beginner at JQuery. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have an idea to deal with this problem. At the end of Gallery.js there is this function call:

```
Gallery.init();
```

I think, one way to solve the problem would be to pass parameters as follows:

```
Gallery.init("#rg-gallery1");
Gallery.init("#rg-gallery2");
```

But how do I modify the init function which is as follows:

```
Gallery = (function() {
    // index of the current item
    var current = 0, 
    // mode : carousel || fullview
    mode            = 'carousel',
    // control if one image is being loaded
    anim = false,
    init = function() {

       // init code here
    }
```

I want to modify INIT function to accept one text parameter now. How do I do that?

Comment: You can not use same ID for different element. ID should be unique for whole html page.

Comment: Agreed. That is why I am going to use two different ID's. But how do I modify $rgGallery to address multiple ID and identify multiple gallery in the page.

Comment: Try this `var $rgGallery = $('#rg-gallery1, #rg-gallery2')`

Comment: That just displays multiple galleries on the page. But if I slide an image in gallery1, the same thing happens automatically in gallery2

Comment: Updated the question with additional information and progress.

Comment: You can use http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: Solved the problem. Added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Now I can display multiple galleries on single page.

Find **gallery.js** file in the "Responsive Image Gallery" Plugin (Link to plugin in the question).

Step 1) Remove $rgGallery

```
var $rgGallery = $('#rg-gallery'),

$esCarousel = $rgGallery.find('div.es-carousel-wrapper'),

$items = $esCarousel.find('ul > li'),

itemsCount = $items.length;
```

So it will appear as follows:

```
//var $rgGallery = $('#rg-gallery'),

var $esCarousel = $rgGallery.find('div.es-carousel-wrapper'),

$items = $esCarousel.find('ul > li'),

itemsCount = $items.length;
```

Step 2) Cut this part of code (don't paste it yet).

Step 3) Wrap the code from

**Gallery = (function()** to **Gallery.init();**

inside a new function called SelectRgGallery which accepts one parameter as follows -

```
SelectRgGallery = function(rgTemp) {

Gallery = (function() {

//existing code

})();

Gallery.init();

}
```

Step 4) Paste the copied code just after opening the SelectRgGallery function.

And add a new code just above the pasted code to declare  $rgGallery variable. We will store the accepted parameter inside $rgGallery variable.

```
SelectRgGallery = function(rgTemp) {

var $rgGallery = $(rgTemp); // store accepted parameter

var $esCarousel = $rgGallery.find('div.es-carousel-wrapper'),

$items = $esCarousel.find('ul > li'),

itemsCount = $items.length;

Gallery = (function() {

//existing code

})();

Gallery.init();

}
```

Step 5) In index.html, add the following script in the footer. (considering we have two galleries in index.html).

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

SelectRgGallery("#rg-gallery1");
SelectRgGallery("#rg-gallery2");

});

</script>
```